# Programmable JDBC driver for mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jdbc, mocking

I'm trying to test legacy Java application, without an ability to re-factor its code at the moment. All I need to do is to understand what SQL requests it is sending through JDBC and when. All these requests I'd like to protocol to a plain text file for future review.

I need to develop a custom JDBC driver which will fool the application, and behave like a normal driver (will accept request, **return some values**, **fail on certain conditions**, etc). A mock structure, as usual...

The question is - do you know any existing frameworks for this task? Ideally I would like to have an ability to configure my driver's behavior through, say, XML file.

Comment: Any updates about JDBC mocking tool ?

Answer (score 2):

p6spy wraps an existing jdbc connection, and allows you to e.g. see what goes back and forth.

See http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/ for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks very interesting. However, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. P6spy is a tool to protocol what's going on, not to change the behavior of JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do unit tests, not an integration tests, than
you can use a very basic and simple approach, using Mockito only, like this:

```
public class JDBCLowLevelTest {

    private TestedClass tested;
    private Connection connection;
    private static Driver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        // (Optional) Print DriverManager logs to system out
        DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter((System.out)));

        // (Optional) Sometimes you need to get rid of a driver (e.g JDBC-ODBC Bridge)
        Driver configuredDriver = DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:odbc:url");

        System.out.println("De-registering the configured driver: " + configuredDriver);
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(configuredDriver);

        // Register the mocked driver
        driver = mock(Driver.class);
        System.out.println("Registering the mock driver: " + driver);
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Let's cleanup the global state
        System.out.println("De-registering the mock driver: " + driver);
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // given
        tested = new TestedClass();

        connection = mock(Connection.class);

        given(driver.acceptsURL(anyString())).willReturn(true);
        given(driver.connect(anyString(), Matchers.<Properties>any()))
                .willReturn(connection);

        given(connection.prepareCall(anyString())).willReturn(statement);        
}
}
```

Than you can test various scenarios, like in any other Mockito test e.g.

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleDoubleException() throws Exception {
    // given
    SomeData someData = new SomeData();

    given(connection.prepareCall(anyString()))
            .willThrow(new SQLException("Prepare call"));
    willThrow(new SQLException("Close exception")).given(connection).close();

    // when
    SomeResponse response = testClass.someMethod(someData);

    // then
    assertThat(response, is(SOME_ERROR));
}
```